# How to install Oracle DBMS_XMLDOM package to 11.2 Database

Tags: oracle11g

I have created an AWS Oracle 11g rds and its up and running. I want to install XML Database and DBMS_XMLDOM package.

Can you please help me with clear instruction.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't already installed? What happens if you `describe xdb.xmldom` or query `dba_objects` (or `all_objects`) for that object name?

Comment: I have tried select * from dba_registry where comp_id = 'XDB'; Its return me nothing.

Comment: OK, I thought it was always on a fresh install, but it seems not. [Installation instructions are in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/appaman.htm#ADXDB5694) - I guess you probably want the manual version, not through DBCA.